# Bootstrap navbar collapse menu does not work over https

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, https

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.2 with Django 1.8.8 to build my website. I am using mod-wsgi version 4.4.23 and Apache 2.2.15 to deploy this on a CentOS VM.

I have a navbar fixed to the top, with a collapsible Signup menu. When I connect to the website over http and click on the menu, the dropdown menu items are listed. But when I connect over https and do the same, the dropdown menu items are not displayed. The same thing happens when I click on minimized navbar menu items when the viewport shrinks.

What could be going wrong?

The base template code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

{% load staticfiles %}

<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

<title>Title</title>


<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="{% static 'bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap_cerulean.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />


<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="{% static 'bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/custom_cerulean.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" /> 

<!-- Load Javascript files  -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    <a class = "navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img style="width:auto; height:160%;" src="{% static "logo.jpg" %}">
    </a>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a class = "navbar-brand" href="{% url 'myapp:profile' %}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
    </a>
    {% endif %}
    </div><!--/.navbar-header -->

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"> Sign Up</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="/myapp/accounts/signup_employer">New Employer</a></li>
                <li><a href="/myapp/accounts/signup_employee">New Employee</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
        <li>
        {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="/myapp/accounts/login"> Login</a>
        {% else %}
        <a href="/myapp/accounts/logout"> Logout</a>
        {% endif %}
        </li>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li>
        <a href="/myapp/accounts/password_change"> Change Password</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/myapp/">MyApp</a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul><!--/.navbar-left -->

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
        <a href="/about_us"> About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/contact_us"> Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul><!--/.navbar-right -->

    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!--/.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you check in the browser's `Developer Tools > Network Tab` if you are getting any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call to load jQuery `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"` is to a http address. It's possible your browser won't load it when you go to HTTPS. That'll break all kinds of things.

Additionally you have some fonts at http:// addresses. Easiest way to fix is to prefix with // .

Right click and Inspect, in most browsers you'll see the error in the Dev Tools.